# Change background color of 1000 jpg files

Tags: windows, linux, jpeg

I have 1000 jpg files in which all have a white background. Is is possible to change the white background color to red (for example) of all the files in order not to have to do it one by one ?

I would prefer to use Linux but I can handle Windows.

For example, change the below logo with a white background to have a red background.

[image]

Comment: Your question is incomplete. How do the files look like? Can you maybe show us an example? What do you want to do? Do you just want to replace `#FFFFFF` white with another color? What do you mean by "modify"? Please [edit] the question to include some more details, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Edited tags - two OS tags aren't generally very informative on their own.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a way to do, then `convert` is your friend.

I have used `convert` for many things, but not specifically for this.   Also, whther you actually have a background color in your images is a question -- it may just be a part of the image which has the same color as the background (which is subtle different) -- however even in that case `convert` may be able to help.

Looking at `man convert` there is an option for changing background color. 
There is also a option `opaque` to change a particular color into the background color.

So playing around with your particular images, and the options you may find what works for your images.

Then the final step would be to write a small shell script to loop though all your images, like this

```
mkdir converted_img
for img in $(ls orig_image/*) ; do
   convert {insert-options-which-does-the-job} orig_image/$img converted_img/$img
done
```

and you should be all done

Comment: There is a `-background` option to `convert`, just to let you know.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, if you don't have the "convert" tool, you must install the ImageMagick set of applications.